# How to group by property values from object java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Suppose I have a below object ,

```
class sample
{
private String type;
private List<String> a1;
private List<String> a2;
private List<String> a3;
}
```

and values for above class,

```
 Sample sample1 = new Sample("type1", Arrays.asList("first", "second"), Arrays.asList("first") , [] );
 Sample sample2 = new Sample("type2", Arrays.asList("first", "second"), Arrays.asList("third") , [] );
```

I expected the below result,

```
first - [ type1, type2 ], second -[ type1, type2 ], third - [ type2 ]
```

Requirement : 
"Grouping the properties of a1, a2, a3 values and map type with other properties"

Kindly help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 2):

First concat each list a1, a2 and a3, mapping it to `Map.entry` where key is string from list and value is `type` (use `distinct` because there is a case when "first" appears both in list a1 and a2). Then do the groupingby with `Map.Entry`.

```
Sample sample1 = new Sample("type1", Arrays.asList("first", "second"), Arrays.asList("first"), Arrays.asList());
Sample sample2 = new Sample("type2", Arrays.asList("first", "second"), Arrays.asList("third"), Arrays.asList());

List<Sample> samples = Arrays.asList(sample1, sample2);

Map<String, List<String>> samplesMap = samples.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.getA1(), s.getA2(), s.getA3())
                .flatMap(l -> l.stream().map(a -> Map.entry(a, s.getType())))
                .distinct()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: the `.distinct()` operation seeems redundant in here

Comment: @Naman `first` comes 2 time in `sample1 `, maybe that's why